# How to make cell grow height same for all in table while typing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi there can you help me I need the cell when I write the height to increase like the ones that I am typing

[image]

As you can see on the photo when I type on cell 1 I want other columns to increase I have made it with red border how I need it to be.

```js
    $("textarea").each(function () {

        this.addEventListener('keydown', autosize);

        function autosize() {
            var el = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                el.style.cssText = 'height:auto; ';
                el.style.cssText = 'height:' + el.scrollHeight + 'px';
            }, 0);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table class="matrix__table">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr class="matrix__table--columns">
                                                        <th></th>
                                                        <th>
                                                            <textarea placeholder="Column 1"
                                                                class="form__input text-area" rows="1"></textarea>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th>
                                                            <textarea placeholder="Column 2"
                                                                class="form__input text-area" rows="1"></textarea>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th>
                                                            <textarea placeholder="Column 3"
                                                                class="form__input text-area" rows="1"></textarea>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th>
                                                            <textarea placeholder="Column 4"
                                                                class="form__input text-area" rows="1"></textarea>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th>
                                                            <textarea placeholder="Column 5"
                                                                class="form__input text-area" rows="1"></textarea>
                                                        </th>

                                                    </tr>

                                                </thead>

                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="matrix__table--row-cell">
                                                            <textarea placeholder="Row 1" class="form__input text-area"
                                                                rows="1"></textarea>
                                                        </td>

                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row1col1"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row1col1">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row1col2"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row1col2">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row1col3"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row1col3">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row1col4"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row1col4">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row1col5"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row1col5">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="matrix__table--row-cell">
                                                            <textarea placeholder="Row 2" class="form__input text-area"
                                                                rows="1"></textarea>
                                                        </td>

                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row2col1"
                                                                name="all2">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row2col1">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row2col2"
                                                                name="all2">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row2col2">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row2col3"
                                                                name="all2">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row2col3">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row2col4"
                                                                name="all2">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row2col4">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row2col5"
                                                                name="all2">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row2col5">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="matrix__table--row-cell">
                                                            <textarea placeholder="Row 3" class="form__input text-area"
                                                                rows="1"></textarea>
                                                        </td>

                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row3col1"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row3col1">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row3col2"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row3col2">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row3col3"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row3col3">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row3col4"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row3col4">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row3col5"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row3col5">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="matrix__table--row-cell">
                                                            <textarea placeholder="Row 4" class="form__input text-area"
                                                                rows="1"></textarea>
                                                        </td>

                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row4col1"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col1">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row4col2"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col2">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row4col3"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col3">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row4col4"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col4">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row4col5"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col5">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="matrix__table--row-cell">
                                                            <textarea placeholder="Row 5" class="form__input text-area"
                                                                rows="1"></textarea>
                                                        </td>

                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row5col1"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col1">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row5col2"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col2">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row5col3"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col3">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row5col4"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col4">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row5col5"
                                                                name="all">
                                                            <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col5">
                                                                <span class="form__radio-button">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>


                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
```

I tried making height auto height inherit but nothing seems to work :/ Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could expand all the text areas in the given row like shown below:

```js
$("textarea").each(function () {
        this.addEventListener('keydown', autosize);
        function autosize() {
            var el = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                el.style.cssText = 'height:auto; ';
                const height = el.scrollHeight + 'px';
                //Find the parent TR and apply the height to all child textareas
                $(el).closest('tr.matrix__table--columns')
                  .find('textarea.form__input')
                  .css('height', height);
            }, 0);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table class="matrix__table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="matrix__table--columns">
            <th></th>
            <th>
                <textarea placeholder="Column 1"
                    class="form__input text-area" rows="1"></textarea>
            </th>
            <th>
                <textarea placeholder="Column 2"
                    class="form__input text-area" rows="1"></textarea>
            </th>
            <th>
                <textarea placeholder="Column 3"
                    class="form__input text-area" rows="1"></textarea>
            </th>
            <th>
                <textarea placeholder="Column 4"
                    class="form__input text-area" rows="1"></textarea>
            </th>
            <th>
                <textarea placeholder="Column 5"
                    class="form__input text-area" rows="1"></textarea>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="matrix__table--row-cell">
                <textarea placeholder="Row 1" class="form__input text-area"
                    rows="1"></textarea>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row1col1"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row1col1">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row1col2"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row1col2">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row1col3"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row1col3">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row1col4"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row1col4">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row1col5"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row1col5">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="matrix__table--row-cell">
                <textarea placeholder="Row 2" class="form__input text-area"
                    rows="1"></textarea>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row2col1"
                    name="all2">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row2col1">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row2col2"
                    name="all2">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row2col2">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row2col3"
                    name="all2">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row2col3">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row2col4"
                    name="all2">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row2col4">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row2col5"
                    name="all2">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row2col5">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="matrix__table--row-cell">
                <textarea placeholder="Row 3" class="form__input text-area"
                    rows="1"></textarea>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row3col1"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row3col1">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row3col2"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row3col2">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row3col3"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row3col3">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row3col4"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row3col4">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row3col5"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row3col5">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="matrix__table--row-cell">
                <textarea placeholder="Row 4" class="form__input text-area"
                    rows="1"></textarea>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row4col1"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col1">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row4col2"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col2">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row4col3"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col3">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row4col4"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col4">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row4col5"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col5">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="matrix__table--row-cell">
                <textarea placeholder="Row 5" class="form__input text-area"
                    rows="1"></textarea>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row5col1"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col1">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row5col2"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col2">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row5col3"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col3">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row5col4"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col4">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" class="form__radio-input" id="row5col5"
                    name="all">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="row4col5">
                    <span class="form__radio-button">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```